# Append part of a file name to another file name

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a long file name that I'm converting and a creating a new file from it.  Im having a bad brain lapse and cant figure out how to take the time stamp from the original file and append it to the end of my new file.

heres an example of the original file name, the `20171005084554` is the part i want to append to my new file.

```
527448423osel5108_k8lx2og.527448423_20171005-095125.20171005084554
```

I run my script

```
#/bin/sh -x

grep "COLUMN:WM\|COLUMN:Vendor" ${1} | sed 's/^COLUMN://' | sed 's/\.//g' > cust_$(date +%Y%m%d)_converted.txt

grep "DATA:" ${1} | sed 's/^DATA://' >> cust_$(date +%Y%m%d)_converted.txt

# mv ${1} processed/
```

Where i have `$(date +%Y%m%d)` is where i want to the other time stamp.

Anyone have any unix / shell magic to help me out?

Comment: If that is the format of your filename, you can simply grep the final 14 characters, store it in a variable with something like `my_var=$(ls | ls *2017* | grep -o '.\{14\}$')` and replace your `$(date +%Y%m%d)` with `$my_var`

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ext=${1##*.}                              # ${1: -14} also possible
file=cust_${ext}_converted.txt

echo "$file"
```

Output:

```
cust_20171005084554_converted.txt
```